# Equivalent distances define same topology

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

I have to prove that

> equivalent distances define same topology.

I know there are similar questions, so please don't have a go at me but I am still confused and they don't answer it in the way I have been taught.

If distances are equivalent then there exist an $\alpha$ and $\beta$ more than zero such that $$\alpha d_1(x,y) \leq d_2(x,y) \leq \beta d_1(x,y)$$

Please help me

Comment: What is the way you were taught? Do you want to use balls or sequences or something else? // You didn't use $\beta$ in the definition of equivalence of metrics. // To get $d_1$ and $d_2$ use `d_{1}` and `d_{2}`.

Comment: Um yea i used balls

Comment: I have to prove equivalent distances define the same topology

Comment: The above is my definition for equivalent distances... i'm assuming that i have an $\epsilon \greater 0$ and a $\delta \greater 0$

Comment: Show every $d_1$-ball is an open $d_2$-set and vice-versa.

Comment: Ok what my lecturer told me to start with was $d1 < \epsilon$ and $d2 < \delta$ then prove delta is less than epsilon and then vice versa

Comment: See [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/109745/28900).

Comment: [Also related](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/183597/equivalent-metrics-determine-the-same-topology/183740#183740).

Answer (score 4):

Assume that $U$ is $d_1$-open. It means that for any $x$ there is an $r>0$ such that $B_x^{d_1}(r)\subseteq U$. But we have $B_x^{d_2}(r/\beta)\subseteq B_x^{d_1}(r)$ by assumption.

The other direction goes similarly, using $\alpha$.