# Why is $U ⊂ \mathbb{R}^n$ open with respect to metric $d_p$ iff it is open with respect to metric $d_q$ for $q ∈ [1, ∞)$?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, metric-spaces

Let's say that for any $p ∈ [1, ∞)$ we have a distance function on $\mathbb{R}^n$ given by $$d_p(x, y) := \left(\sum^n_{j=1}|x_i - y_i|^p\right)^{\frac{1}{p}}$$

How would I show that a set $U ⊂ \mathbb{R}^n$ is open with respect to the metric $d_p$ if and only if it is open with respect to the metric $d_q$ for any $q ∈ [1, ∞)$?

Answer (score 0):

> Hint: if two distances are equivalent, they induce the same topology (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/381704/equivalent-distances-define-same-topology)).

So you can either prove that such distances are equivalent, by hand, or you can more generally prove that all norms on a finite dimensional space are equivalent and notice your distances are induced by norms.